# Range of function $f(5x-4)$. If range of function is $(3,8)$

Tags: functions

> If the domain and range of function $f(x)$ is $[-4,5]$ and $(3,8)$.Then Domain and range of $f(5x-4)$ is

What i try :: Here $-4\leq x \leq 5$. Then $-24 \leq 5x-4\leq 21$. So domain of $f(5x-4)$ is $[-24,21]$ But i did not understand How can i find range of function.Help me please.

Comment: The  range is same as $(3,8)$

Comment: Your domain is wrong. $f(5x-4)$ is defined iff $5 x - 4\in [-4, 5]$. That's how you can find the domain.

Comment: How this can be possible. I did not understand it.please explain me.

Comment: To professor Kavi Rama,murthy. Please explain me How can i find domain of function.Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about the range, but I think the domain is [0,1.8] instead of your answer. Since if you plugged 21 into f(5x-4), you have f(101), which exceeds the domain of f(x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that the domain of $f$ is $[-4, 5]$ and that the range is $(3, 8)$ means the following:

1. $f(x)$ is defined if and only if $-4 \le x \le 5$
2. For every $x$, one has $3 < f(x) < 8$
3. For every value $v\in (3, 8)$, there is at least one $x\in [-4, 5]$ such that $f(x)=v$

With this we see that

1. $f(5 x- 4)$ is defined if and only if $-4 \le 5 x- 4\le 5$, that is to say $x\in [0, 1.8]$.
2. For every $x$ one has $3 <f(5x-4)< 8$
3. For every value $v\in(3, 8)$, let $y\in [-4,5]$ satisfy $f(y)= v$, let $x\in[0, 1.8]$ be such that $5x-4=y$. One has $f(5x-4)=v$.

Hence the domain of $f(5 x - 4)$ is $[0, 1.8]$ and its range is $(3,8)$

Answer (score 1):

Please take domain of the function as $-4\leq (5x-4) \leq 5$ and the range of the function remains $(3,8)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Determine the inverse function of $u(x)=5x-4$, and deduce $u^{-1}\bigl([-4,5]\bigr)$.